# How to encode accented and other foreign characters to UTF8 in perl

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I've tried everywhere to learn and get my head around this but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Lets take a string:

> Macaroon dessert muffin. Sugar plum cookie macaroon soufflé lollipop
>   candy brownie tiramisu croissant. Wafer ice cream chocolate bar
>   gummies. Cheesecake powder chupa chups. Donut pastry candy canes.
>   Liquorice tootsie roll candy canes jelly-o. Sesame snaps applicake
>   sugar plum cupcake apple pie. Chocolate ice cream cotton candy
>   soufflé. Apple pie danish unerdwear.com wafer unerdwear.com muffin
>   applicake pudding. Jelly cotton candy brownie lollipop macaroon sweet
>   roll carrot cake chocolate bar. Tart lollipop cookie unerdwear.com
>   gummies powder. Jelly halvah apple pie pudding caramels marzipan.
>   Marzipan jelly-o topping pie powder icing. Gummies jelly-o tiramisu
>   bear claw brownie cheesecake. Icing pie oat cake lollipop carrot cake
>   toffee. Donut jelly sugar plum muffin. Fruitcake tiramisu jujubes
>   muffin tart jelly-o pie fruitcake. Unerdwear.com jujubes unerdwear.com
>   gummi bears jelly beans brownie macaroon. Marzipan halvah cake tootsie
>   roll cotton candy cotton candy donut. Soufflé wafer candy canes carrot
>   cake. Cheesecake muffin powder gummies carrot cake. Halvah ice cream
>   applicake liquorice macaroon apple pie cupcake. Cake dragée liquorice.
>   Sugar plum biscuit halvah. Carrot cake candy canes sweet candy. Candy
>   canes marzipan marshmallow danish cake jelly-o brownie cookie oat
>   cake.

When I do:

```
Encode::encode('UTF-8', $text);
```

on that string, the word Soufflé gets encoded to SoufflÃ©.

When I look at this, I don't recognise it as any code point or as any valid encoding mapping (i.e. `&#xe9;`). How am I to expect it to reach its destination in a way that it can be read correctly? In other words, why does Perl give me Ã© when I've encoded it as UTF8 and it should have given me `&#xe9;`?

```
xmlbody($text);

sub xmlbody {
    $description = shift;

    use XML::Writer;
    my $writer = XML::Writer->new( OUTPUT => 'self', ENCODING => 'utf-8' );
    my $writer->xmlDecl('utf-8');

    ## ...structure

    $writer->cdataElement('description',$description);

    ## ...more structure

    $writer->end();
}
```

`use utf8;` doesn't seem to be encoding the special characters in the above mentioned string, it still gives "Ã©". Would having `$writer->xmlDecl('utf-8')` be the equivalent of `use open qw(:std :utf8)`, since I'm not using a filehandle or stdin/stdout?

Comment: **You should not be explicitly using the `Encode` module at all!**  Declare your source code as utf8 via `use utf8`, then declare your output utf8 via `use open qw(:std :utf8)`.  If you want to change the trans-ASCII code points into some XML entity, that is something else altogether.

Comment: @tchrist Interesting, I see it used all over the place in some of the code I work with. My problem is sending text encoded in CDATA tags. The reason I didn't mention that was because I believe the error was more native to my Perl code

Comment: Well, there’s no telling where your string example above came from. If it is a string literal in your program, then you need to `use utf8` in that source unit / file.  If it is coming from outside your program, you need to set the encoding on that stream if it a stream.  If it is coming from somewhere else, like an argument or environment variable or database, then there are things you will have to do.

Comment: @tchrist I've included a short example of what I've done in order to make sure that the characters in my XML are encoded using utf-8 although it is giving me the `Ã©` characters when trying to encode é

Comment: @tchrist, That will give you the same problem the OP is already suffering from: Double encoding. XML::Writer is already encoding the output (as it should).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I look at this, I don't recognise it as any code point or as any valid encoding mapping

If you look at [the relevant page on fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm), you'll see what is happening.

Initially, in your program you have a Unicode character "é". The Unicode character code for that is U+00E9. When you encode that character as UTF-8, you get a character that consists of two bytes - 0xC3 0xA9. If you look at [the codepage for ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1#Codepage_layout), you'll see that 0xC3 is "Ã" and 0xA9 is "©".

If you try to display that two-byte character on a device that understands UTF-8 and is expecting UTF-8 then you'll get "é". Otherwise the device will use its native character encoding (which is likely to be ISO-8859-1) and you'll get the [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) that you've seen.

As [tchrist says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723053/how-to-encode-accented-and-other-foreign-characters-to-utf8-in-perl#comment38354049_24723053), the easiest way to handle this is to use Perl's tools that take care of it without you having to think about it.

Comment: Amazing explanation, that makes it a whole lot clearer for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not the literal in string expression in Perl.